# SVG Animation Explanation

Tags: css, animation, svg

I am having trouble figuring out why this svg animation from codepen works. For the animation that moves the sprinkles left to right, it keeps setting the animation back to the original state. The question I have here is why does the translateX property only go to 154.5px.

I forked this from a codepen I saw by  the way. Anyway, I am completely confused how they came up with this number. What math is needed to get this number?

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
#Circle{
  display:none
}
@keyframes bottommotion {
  0%   {transform: rotate(0deg)}
  14%   {transform: rotate(10deg)}
  29%   {transform: rotate(-10deg)}
  45%   {transform: rotate(0deg)}
  55%   {transform: translate(0px, 38px)}
  88%   {transform: translate(0px, 0px)}
}
#Bottom { 
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-timing-function: cubic;   
  animation-name: bottommotion;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes topmotion {
  0%   {transform: rotate(0deg)}
  23%   {transform: rotate(10deg)}
  38%   {transform: rotate(-10deg)}
  45%   {transform: rotate(0deg)}
  55%   {transform: translate(0px, -54px)}
  100%   {transform: translate(0px, 0px)}
}
#Top { 
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-timing-function: cubic;   
  animation-name: topmotion;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes spotmotion {
  0%   {transform: translate(0px,0px)}
  100%   {transform: translate(154.5px,0px)}

}

#Spots { 
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-timing-function: linear;   
  animation-name: spotmotion;
  animation-duration: .23s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes shadowmotion {
  0%   {opacity:0.75;  transform:translate(0px, 0px)}
  45%   {opacity:0.75; transform:translate(0px, 0px)}
  55%   {opacity:0.95;  transform:translate(0px, -6px)}
  95%   {opacity:0.75; transform:translate(0px, 0px)} 
  100%   {opacity:0.75;  transform:translate(0px, 0px)}
}
#Shadow { 
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-timing-function: cubic;   
  animation-name: shadowmotion;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="center"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                         width="505.821px" height="325.822px" viewBox="0 0 505.821 325.822" enable-background="new 0 0 505.821 325.822"
                         xml:space="preserve">
  <g id="Background">
    <rect width="505.821" height="325.822"/>
  </g>
  <g id="Spots">
    <g>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M-146.92,271.615h-69.574c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C-143.521,273.137-145.042,271.615-146.92,271.615z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M9.08,271.615h-69.574c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4H9.08
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C12.479,273.137,10.958,271.615,9.08,271.615z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M165.08,271.615H95.505c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C168.479,273.137,166.958,271.615,165.08,271.615z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M321.08,271.615h-69.574c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C324.479,273.137,322.958,271.615,321.08,271.615z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M477.08,271.615h-69.574c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C480.479,273.137,478.958,271.615,477.08,271.615z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M633.08,271.615h-69.574c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C636.479,273.137,634.958,271.615,633.08,271.615z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M789.08,271.615h-69.574c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C792.479,273.137,790.958,271.615,789.08,271.615z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M-195.406,198.945h-69.574c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C-192.006,200.467-193.528,198.945-195.406,198.945z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M-39.406,198.945h-69.574c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C-36.006,200.467-37.528,198.945-39.406,198.945z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M116.594,198.945H47.02c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C119.994,200.467,118.472,198.945,116.594,198.945z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M272.594,198.945H203.02c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C275.994,200.467,274.472,198.945,272.594,198.945z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M428.594,198.945H359.02c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C431.994,200.467,430.472,198.945,428.594,198.945z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M584.594,198.945H515.02c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C587.994,200.467,586.472,198.945,584.594,198.945z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M740.594,198.945H671.02c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C743.994,200.467,742.472,198.945,740.594,198.945z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M-146.92,120.026h-69.574c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C-143.521,121.549-145.042,120.026-146.92,120.026z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M9.08,120.026h-69.574c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4H9.08
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C12.479,121.549,10.958,120.026,9.08,120.026z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M165.08,120.026H95.505c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C168.479,121.549,166.958,120.026,165.08,120.026z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M321.08,120.026h-69.574c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C324.479,121.549,322.958,120.026,321.08,120.026z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M477.08,120.026h-69.574c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C480.479,121.549,478.958,120.026,477.08,120.026z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M633.08,120.026h-69.574c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C636.479,121.549,634.958,120.026,633.08,120.026z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M789.08,120.026h-69.574c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C792.479,121.549,790.958,120.026,789.08,120.026z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M-195.406,52.356h-69.574c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C-192.006,53.879-193.528,52.356-195.406,52.356z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M-39.406,52.356h-69.574c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C-36.006,53.879-37.528,52.356-39.406,52.356z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M116.594,52.356H47.02c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C119.994,53.879,118.472,52.356,116.594,52.356z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M272.594,52.356H203.02c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C275.994,53.879,274.472,52.356,272.594,52.356z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M428.594,52.356H359.02c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C431.994,53.879,430.472,52.356,428.594,52.356z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M584.594,52.356H515.02c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C587.994,53.879,586.472,52.356,584.594,52.356z"/>
      <path fill="#00192a" d="M740.594,52.356H671.02c-1.877,0-3.4,1.522-3.4,3.399c0,1.879,1.523,3.4,3.4,3.4h69.574
                              c1.878,0,3.399-1.521,3.399-3.4C743.994,53.879,742.472,52.356,740.594,52.356z"/>
    </g>
    <g opacity="0.86">
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M-205.688,16.326h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.015,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.267-1.015,2.267-2.267S-204.437,16.326-205.688,16.326z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M-49.688,16.326h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.015,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.267-1.015,2.267-2.267S-48.437,16.326-49.688,16.326z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M106.312,16.326h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.015,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.267-1.015,2.267-2.267S107.563,16.326,106.312,16.326z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M262.311,16.326h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.015,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.268-1.015,2.268-2.267S263.563,16.326,262.311,16.326z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M418.311,16.326h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.016,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.268-1.015,2.268-2.267S419.563,16.326,418.311,16.326z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M574.311,16.326h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.016,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.268-1.015,2.268-2.267S575.563,16.326,574.311,16.326z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M730.311,16.326h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.016,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.268-1.015,2.268-2.267S731.563,16.326,730.311,16.326z"/>
    </g>
    <g opacity="0.86">
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M-278.269,85.058h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.015,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.267-1.015,2.267-2.267S-277.017,85.058-278.269,85.058z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M-122.269,85.058h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.015,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.267-1.015,2.267-2.267S-121.017,85.058-122.269,85.058z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M33.731,85.058h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.015,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.267-1.015,2.267-2.267S34.983,85.058,33.731,85.058z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M189.731,85.058h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.015,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.268-1.015,2.268-2.267S190.983,85.058,189.731,85.058z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M345.731,85.058h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.016,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.268-1.015,2.268-2.267S346.983,85.058,345.731,85.058z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M501.731,85.058h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.016,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.268-1.015,2.268-2.267S502.983,85.058,501.731,85.058z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M657.731,85.058h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.016,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.268-1.015,2.268-2.267S658.983,85.058,657.731,85.058z"/>
    </g>
    <g opacity="0.86">
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M-205.688,159.152h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.015,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.267-1.015,2.267-2.267S-204.437,159.152-205.688,159.152z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M-49.688,159.152h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.015,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.267-1.015,2.267-2.267S-48.437,159.152-49.688,159.152z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M106.312,159.152h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.015,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.267-1.015,2.267-2.267S107.563,159.152,106.312,159.152z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M262.311,159.152h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.015,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.268-1.015,2.268-2.267S263.563,159.152,262.311,159.152z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M418.311,159.152h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.016,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.268-1.015,2.268-2.267S419.563,159.152,418.311,159.152z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M574.311,159.152h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.016,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.268-1.015,2.268-2.267S575.563,159.152,574.311,159.152z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M730.311,159.152h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.016,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.268-1.015,2.268-2.267S731.563,159.152,730.311,159.152z"/>
    </g>
    <g opacity="0.86">
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M-205.688,301.978h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.015,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.267-1.015,2.267-2.267S-204.437,301.978-205.688,301.978z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M-49.688,301.978h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.015,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.267-1.015,2.267-2.267S-48.437,301.978-49.688,301.978z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M106.312,301.978h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.015,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.267-1.015,2.267-2.267S107.563,301.978,106.312,301.978z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M262.311,301.978h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.015,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.268-1.015,2.268-2.267S263.563,301.978,262.311,301.978z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M418.311,301.978h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.016,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.268-1.015,2.268-2.267S419.563,301.978,418.311,301.978z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M574.311,301.978h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.016,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.268-1.015,2.268-2.267S575.563,301.978,574.311,301.978z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M730.311,301.978h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.016,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.268-1.015,2.268-2.267S731.563,301.978,730.311,301.978z"/>
    </g>
    <g opacity="0.86">
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M-278.269,227.884h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.015,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.267-1.015,2.267-2.267S-277.017,227.884-278.269,227.884z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M-122.269,227.884h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.015,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.267-1.015,2.267-2.267S-121.017,227.884-122.269,227.884z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M33.731,227.884h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.015,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.267-1.015,2.267-2.267S34.983,227.884,33.731,227.884z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M189.731,227.884h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.015,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.268-1.015,2.268-2.267S190.983,227.884,189.731,227.884z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M345.731,227.884h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.016,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.268-1.015,2.268-2.267S346.983,227.884,345.731,227.884z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M501.731,227.884h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.016,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.268-1.015,2.268-2.267S502.983,227.884,501.731,227.884z"/>
      <path fill="#0090A5" d="M657.731,227.884h-24.8c-1.251,0-2.267,1.015-2.267,2.267s1.016,2.267,2.267,2.267h24.8
                              c1.252,0,2.268-1.015,2.268-2.267S658.983,227.884,657.731,227.884z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g id="Shadow">
    <ellipse fill="#00243C" cx="252.403" cy="291.789" rx="68" ry="20"/>
  </g>
  <g id="Bottom">
    <g>
      <g>
        <path fill="#60C29E" d="M177.332,156.984c0.001,50.103,33.611,90.72,75.071,90.72s75.068-40.617,75.069-90.72H177.332z"/>
        <path fill="#87C65F" d="M252.402,156.984v90.72c0.001,0,0.001,0,0.001,0c41.46,0,75.068-40.617,75.069-90.72H252.402z"/>
        <path fill="#38A479" d="M304.012,156.984H200.789c0,50.101,23.11,90.718,51.611,90.72c0,0,0.002,0,0.003,0
                                C280.91,247.703,304.012,207.087,304.012,156.984z"/>
        <path fill="#32B44E" d="M252.401,156.984v90.72c0.001,0,0.001,0,0.002,0c28.507-0.002,51.609-40.617,51.609-90.72H252.401z"/>
        <path fill="#00904C" d="M271.169,156.984h-37.536c0,50.103,8.404,90.718,18.769,90.72l0,0
                                C262.768,247.703,271.169,207.087,271.169,156.984z"/>
        <ellipse fill="#006744" cx="252.403" cy="156.984" rx="75.071" ry="18.144"/>
        <ellipse fill="#F69077" cx="252.403" cy="156.984" rx="60.808" ry="14.697"/>
        <ellipse fill="#EF413C" cx="252.403" cy="156.984" rx="53.774" ry="12.996"/>
        <path d="M217.479,156.382c2.512,2.117,2.337,6.792,2.299,6.825c-0.033,0.031-5.408,0.331-7.918-1.787
                 c-2.511-2.117-3.289-4.96-1.736-6.353C211.677,153.676,214.967,154.264,217.479,156.382z"/>
        <path d="M237.369,154.375c1.364,2.8-0.894,7.048-0.942,7.066c-0.047,0.017-5.126-1.529-6.491-4.329
                 c-1.363-2.8-0.805-5.684,1.249-6.439C233.237,149.917,236.004,151.575,237.369,154.375z"/>
        <path d="M257.023,154.546c0,3.04-3.982,6.188-4.036,6.186c-0.05,0-4.036-3.146-4.036-6.186c0-3.041,1.808-5.507,4.036-5.508
                 C255.216,149.04,257.023,151.504,257.023,154.546z"/>
        <path d="M276.065,156.733c-1.363,2.8-6.441,4.348-6.489,4.329c-0.047-0.018-2.309-4.266-0.947-7.064
                 c1.366-2.802,4.135-4.459,6.188-3.704C276.869,151.049,277.427,153.931,276.065,156.733z"/>
        <path d="M294.224,160.676c-2.509,2.117-7.88,1.819-7.916,1.786c-0.035-0.03-0.213-4.709,2.296-6.826
                 c2.513-2.116,5.808-2.704,7.358-1.312C297.515,155.715,296.737,158.56,294.224,160.676z"/>
      </g>
      <!--   <circle opacity="0" fill="#00A654" cx="252.402" cy="156.984" r="90.696"/> -->
    </g>
  </g>
  <g id="Top">
    <g>
      <g>
        <path fill="#60C29E" d="M252.403,175.152c41.46,0,75.069-8.123,75.069-18.144c0,0,0,0,0-0.001
                                c0-50.104-33.609-90.719-75.069-90.719s-75.071,40.615-75.071,90.719c0,0,0,0.001,0,0.001
                                C177.332,167.029,210.943,175.152,252.403,175.152z"/>
        <path fill="#38A479" d="M252.403,175.152c19.724,0,37.659-1.841,51.058-4.848c0.361-4.34,0.552-8.779,0.552-13.297
                                c0-50.104-23.103-90.719-51.61-90.719c-28.502,0-51.613,40.615-51.613,90.719c0,4.518,0.191,8.956,0.554,13.297
                                C214.74,173.311,232.678,175.152,252.403,175.152z"/>
        <path opacity="0.62" fill="#00A654" d="M252.403,175.152c6.354,0,12.52-0.192,18.413-0.551c0.23-5.692,0.354-11.574,0.354-17.594
                                               c0-50.104-8.401-90.719-18.768-90.719c-10.364,0-18.769,40.615-18.769,90.719c0,6.02,0.123,11.9,0.354,17.594
                                               C239.88,174.959,246.048,175.152,252.403,175.152z"/>
        <path fill="#87C65F" d="M257.023,66.464v108.65c39.306-0.577,70.449-8.461,70.449-18.106c0,0,0,0,0-0.001
                                C327.472,108.779,296.33,69.349,257.023,66.464z"/>
        <path fill="#32B44E" d="M252.403,175.152c19.724,0,37.659-1.841,51.058-4.848c0.361-4.34,0.552-8.779,0.552-13.297
                                c0-50.104-23.103-90.719-51.61-90.719L252.403,175.152C252.403,175.152,252.403,175.152,252.403,175.152z"/>
        <path fill="#00904C" d="M252.403,175.152c6.354,0,12.52-0.192,18.413-0.551c0.23-5.692,0.354-11.574,0.354-17.594
                                c0-50.104-8.401-90.719-18.768-90.719c-10.364,0-18.769,40.615-18.769,90.719c0,6.02,0.123,11.9,0.354,17.594
                                C239.88,174.959,246.048,175.152,252.403,175.152z"/>
      </g>
      <!--   <circle opacity="0" fill="#00A654" cx="252.402" cy="156.984" r="90.696"/> -->
    </g>
  </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/Jesders88/pen/mOXVRK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the coordinates of the spots, or their bounding boxes, you can see that the horizontal distance between them is 156.

Why did the author go with 154.5 instead?  Who knows.  It may have been a mistake. More likely it was because they thought it looked better.  If you used 156, you might get stuttering due to duplicate frames at the 0 and 156 offsets.

Try changing it to 156 and see whether you think it looks worse or not.

Comment: So what am I looking at in that SVG above that will tell me the distance between paths? Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: On the assumption that all the spots were copies of each other, just respositioned. You could look at their start positions.  For example, look at the start of the first (`M-146.92,271.615`) and second (`M9.08,271.615`) paths.  The M stands for Move (ie position the start of the path). That's followed by X and Y coords. In this case the X coord on each is -146.92 and 9.08. The difference between these two is 156.  The same applies to second and third paths etc.  We can tell they are in rows of paths because the Y coords are the same.

Comment: Perfect Explantation. Thanks